# How to access Docker web app from host OS?

Tags: vagrant, docker

I've followed the tutorial on the docker.io website here:

http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/python_web_app/

How would I access this app from a browser on my host OS?

Answer (score 0):

Docker Remote API provides a way of accessing your Docker images and containers and performing many operations on them, through your Browser. 
[Here is the link for Docker API v1.6 Documentation](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/api/docker_remote_api_v1.6/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to access the web application itself not the Docker API. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/python_web_app/) explains how this works:

```
WEB_PORT=$(sudo docker port $WEB_WORKER 5000)
```

> Look up the public-facing port which is NAT-ed. Find the private port used by the container and store it inside of the WEB_PORT variable.

```
# install curl if necessary, then ...
curl http://127.0.0.1:$WEB_PORT
  Hello world!
```

> Access the web app using curl. If everything worked as planned you should see the line “Hello world!” inside of your console.

Inside the container the application is listening on port 5000. This is translated automatically to an external port number accessible outside of the container. This makes sense because it allows multiple copies of your application to coexist on the same machine, each mapping port 5000 to a uniquely accessible port number for each app instance.

The [documentation](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/port_redirection/) on port redirection has more details.